# How do I secure my URL while passing it to AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have used a proxy lambda function to be called in the API gateway. I am able to pass in the URL and get the response back from the Lambda. My issue is how do I secure the data that I am sending in the URL...

I am sending the username and password in the URL as the query string. Since I will call this API from the front end, it will be logged in the server logs.How do I secure that query string.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Do not send sensitive data in the query string. This data could be logged or cached by clients and servers.

If you absolutely need to send this data in the request, send it in the request body. Ideally, you should encrypt this data using a public key and decrypt in your Lambda function using a private key (i.e. using KMS)

Comment: Thank you Ryan, based on your suggestion, in your first apporach do you mean that I should include the username and password in the request body and then map the requestbody to the event that needs to be passed to the lambda function. Do I need to have my own mapping template defined in the integration request when I am creating the API in the Aws-api gateway. How actually I can send the parameter in the request body for the API